# Query unexpectedly returning dates from previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running this query in SQL Server and it is returning dates from 2023?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblVisitor
WHERE checkInDate BETWEEN '01/02/2024' AND '06/02/2024'
```

When looking closely at the tables, I noticed that the dates in the tables appear to be set as `VarChar(50)` and are just plain text in the following format: `dd/mm/yyyy`. I'm wondering if it is because it needs converted?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: For whatever DBMS you are using, look up how to convert varchar to date.

Comment: If you store dates as plain text, not as some internal date datatype, always store them in YYYYMMDD format (you can add slashes, dots or dashes if you find that better readable).

Comment: `checkInDate` should have been created as a `date`. SQL Server has no idea that the contents of this `varchar(50)` are a string in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Under string comparison rules even `03/01/0001` is in that range

Comment: Your sql will lead to a string comparison, so a string containing: '02/02/1901' will be sorted between your selection, because 02 is between 01 and 06. As others mentioned, you should probably do some sort of conversion, check out convert function in sql server documentation, especially with style 103

Comment: Another problem: Does `01/02/2024` mean February 1st, 2024 or January 2nd, 2024?  In fact, SQL Server has a handy `TRY_CONVERT()` function which might help, but you would need to give it the format.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at converting it. It's strange because the checkInDate was in dd/mm/yyyy format and the checkOutDate is in the US format and both strings which is confusing. thanks for pointing me in the right direction, now I understand I need to convert it.

Comment: "dates in the tables appear to be set as VarChar(50)" Step 1: refactor the database properly, no reason to take that much space for dates and make code harder etc.

Answer (score 10):

> When looking closely at the tables, I noticed that the dates in the tables appear to be set as VarChar(50) and are just plain text in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy

This was an extremely poor schema choice — so bad it's not even funny — and it directly explains your issue. If you have date values stored in a string/varchar field, then comparisons will do string comparisons **without any regard for the date values**.

So given this expression:

```
checkInDate BETWEEN '01/02/2024' AND '06/02/2024'
```

Assuming the literals use the same `dd/mm/yyyy` as the column values, dates from **ANY YEAR** during most of the first week of the month will match that check, just like you observed. For example, `02/05/2018` is valid, even though both the month and year are wrong, because '02' is greater than '01' and less than '06', and that's as far as a string comparison needs to go. The computer does not care or even have any concept this looks strange or that these values are intended to be used as dates.

**This is one reason (among MANY) you should not store dates in varchar columns.**

If you MUST store dates as strings, *at least* store them in a format that sorts correctly, putting the *most significant* element first and moving towards least significant last... effectively the exact opposite from what you have. For SQL Server, specifically, for historical reasons this is the *basic/unseparated variant* of [the ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]
```

Given the further likelihood you will not be able to change the existing table, you will have to first parse the values as dates. Only then can you accurately make the comparison. Furthermore, standard practice for date values is to *avoid the `BETWEEN` operator*, and instead use a "half-open" comparison with an exclusive upper bounds check for one day past the end of the desired range.

The result looks like this:

```
CONVERT(Date, checkInDate, 103) >= '20240201' AND CONVERT(Date, checkInDate, 103) < '20240207'
```

If this looks odd to you, remember this: different cultures and languages have different expectations around formatting and communicating date values. When communicating in a given language, you should expect to use that language's norms and conventions, regardless of what you learned in your own culture. It doesn't matter if the language in question is a programming language. THIS is the convention needed for SQL with SQL Server.

This also shows yet another reason why you should not store dates in varchar columns. The need to do the conversion has two serious performance implications:

1. Any index on the column will not be at all useful for this query (really: with that format, *any query at all*), because the converted values no longer match what is stored in the index. This cuts to the core of database performance.
2. This conversion must be done for *every row in the table*... even if you only expect a few rows in the result set, even for rows that fail the comparison check, because you can't know if a row matches or not until the conversion is completed. For large tables, this can get ridiculously slow. MUCH better to just store the converted value in the first place.

If you like the `MM/dd/yyyy` format, *you can use that format when you output the values*. This can be done as part of a `SELECT` query, or, even better, let the report tool or application code handle the formatting.

Comment: I will create a new column in the SQL database that is of date value and then pull the existing dates from the varchar column and put them in the new column that uses date.